# Regex function rename file issue

Tags: java, regex, file-rename

I'm using following code to rename a file automatically:

```
    public static String getNewNameForCopyFile(final String originalName, final boolean firstCall) {
    if (firstCall) {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\..*)?");
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(originalName);
        if (m.matches()) { //group 1 is the name, group 2 is the extension
            String name = m.group(1);
            String extension = m.group(2);
            if (extension == null) {
                extension = "";
            }
            return name + "-Copy1" + extension;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    } else {
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(-Copy(\\d+))?(\\..*)?");
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(originalName);
        if (m.matches()) { //group 1 is the prefix, group 2 is the number, group 3 is the suffix
            String prefix = m.group(1);
            String numberMatch = m.group(3);
            String suffix = m.group(4);
            return prefix + "-Copy" + (numberMatch == null ? 1 : (Integer.parseInt(numberMatch) + 1)) + (suffix == null ? "" : suffix);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

This works mostly only with following filename I'm having a problem and I don't know how to adapt my code: 
test.abc.txt
The renamed file becomes 'test-Copy1.abc.txt' but should be 'test.abc-Copy1.txt'.

Do you know how can I achieve this with my method?

Comment: `return prefix + "." + suffix + "-Copy" + numberMatch + ".txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert a copy number before the last dot (`'.'`) in the file name if there is any, and instead you get insertion before the first dot.  This arises because you are using a reluctant quantifier for the first group, and the second group is able to match a filename tail containing any number of dots.  I think you will do better with this:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\.[^.]*)?");
```

Note that if it is present, the second group starts with a dot, but cannot contain other dots.

Comment: I believe this will handle all cases -- zero, one, or multiple dots.

Comment: This seems to work, I will test if further and after all tests passed through I will accept the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is find the last '.' in the firstname, correct? I that case you need to use greedy matching .* (which matches as much as possible) instead of .*?

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)(\\..*)")
```

You will need to handle the case with no dot seperately:

```
if (originalName.indexOf('.') == -1) 
  return originalName + "-Copy1"
Your other code
```

Comment: This does not serve the case where there is no dot at all in the file name, which the original code does handle.  The observation about greedy vs. reluctant quantifiers is good, though.

Comment: I noticed it will not handle the case with no dot. You will have to handle that case separately.  if (originalName.indexOf('.') == -1) needs to be handled differently.